# Is there a requirement in BizTalk that requires a message coming in be sent out?

Tags: biztalk

I have an orchestration that processes incoming messages that make a data call. If data is returned, a new message is created and sent back to the receive port via a "mover" BizTalk application. The original message is no longer needed, so I've been sending it to a discard folder. Is there a requirement in BizTalk that requires a message coming in to be sent out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each message that comes into BizTalk needs to be routed somewhere yes, otherwise it will suspend with a routing failure.

However as you are using an Orchestration, once it has consumed the message, and you don't need to send the original message anywhere from the Orchestration if you don't need it, when the Orchestration ends, that message will be gone

In message only scenarios, where you don't have an orchestration your options are

1. A file send port to a folder, where you have a script to clean them up
2. A null adapter on a send port, a null adapter is a custom adapter that takes the message from the message box and  just discards it.

Comment: So, the orchestration is like a Method in C#, for each message the orchestration is called, runs then ends, correct?  I'm assuming so but I have to be sure, since this process with be processing messages 24/7.  Thanks the reply.

Comment: @jamestreinen  Usually yes, although you can make it continue to run as well, but by default it will end.